# Thrush texts in apps on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, text

Greeting, I have some problem with text for some apps, the problem is when I want to choose an option, the text of this option going to thrush (in picture)

[Thrush text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmw3F.png)

,It isn't just about this app (newsflash) it's about more than this app and I don't know how should I resolve this problem, even I don't know what should I search in internet!
Please if anyone had this issue before or have suggestion feel free.

Comment: A workaround to disable to GPU could either be `nomodeset` on the kernel command line, or `LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1` in `~/.profile`